# CSS bug with umlauts (äöü) using @font-face

Tags: html, css, web, fonts, font-face

I have integrated wf_SegoeUILight as a font into my website [goo.gl/Ae4VK](http://goo.gl/Ae4VK). However in my umlauts **äöü** it displays the font incorrectly. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

**Here is the incorrect umlaut "ü"**
[image: Incorrect umlaut]

**The original from Microsoft looks pretty good**

[image: microsoft original]

Comment: Can you provide example markup?

Comment: Does the font actually contain `ÄÖÜ`?

Comment: @Pekka웃 yes the font seems to contain those, since it is properly displayed on the microsoft website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your font do not contain äöü. So it renders in another font which explain the difference.

Comment: How do you explain, that the same font renders the äöü on the Microsoft website then, for example on http://office.microsoft.com/de-de/business/

Comment: @Jack you're using a different font than them.

Answer (score 1):

The font you are embedding,

```
http://i.s-microsoft.com/fonts/Segoe-UI/Cyrillic/Light/latest.ttf
```

doesn't seem to be containing German Umlauts, so the browser substitutes the characters with the next font in the list that does.

The Microsoft web site that you refer to seems to be using a different font file,

```
http://i.s-microsoft.com/fonts/Segoe-UI/West-European/Light/latest.ttf
```

Answer (score 0):

The page looks correct here in browsers both new (Chrome) and old (IE8). So probably your browser is caching something.

Try it from a different machine. Of course, it's possible that *my* browsers have cached the 'right' font and are hiding the problem.